# Firebase's exists() function behaving abruptly

Tags: android, firebase

[image][image]

Im using `exists()` method of the snapshot object in `Firebase` to check if user exists on pressing the `SignUp(register)` button. But as soon as I press the button, both the if and else conditions are executed(else first). What is going wrong?

```
    final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                public static final String TAG = "user_REG";

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.child(mobileNumber.getText().toString()).exists()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: if fired");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: else fired");
                        if(confirmPass.getText().toString().trim().equals(userPass.getText().toString().trim())){
                            userModel userModel = new userModel(fullName.getText().toString(), userPass.getText().toString());
                            databaseReference.child(mobileNumber.getText().toString()).setValue(userModel);
                            Toast.makeText(user_reg.this, "Successfully Signed Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(user_reg.this, "Your Passwords do not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Why do you say the both are executed? What is the exact output in your logcat?

Comment: kindly check the first screenshot, thats my logcat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First time `mobileNumber` doesn't exist, So else part is executed and child node value is added and as data is added under same node, `onDataChange` will fire again and this time, `if` part will be executed.

To prevent the `onDataChange` to call twice, Use `SingleEventListener` instead of `ValueEventListener` Like this

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
       // do your stuff here with value
   }
   @Override
   public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
   }
});
```

Comment: how to prevent onDataChange from firing up again so that I can create a neat and clean signup page?